# ViewPager Fragment: переключаться между окнами горизонтальным слайдингом

Tags: android, android-fragment

Помогите разобраться с `ViewPager Fragment (Android)`. Мне нужно при запуске создать 3 окна, и переключаться между ними горизонтальным слайдингом. Тоесть как в `PlayMarkete`, пальцем провел вправо переход на 2 окно, влево переход на 1 окно. Или киньте, пожалуйста, ссылку на  русскую документацию про `ViewPager`

Comment: Хорошо, а в чем у вас затруднения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ViewPager`](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/228-urok-125-viewpager.html)

> `ViewPager` позволяет нам организовать удобный и красивый просмотр данных с возможностью перелистывания влево-вправо. Сам `ViewPager` отвечает за показ и прокрутку. Но ему нужен еще `PagerAdapter`, который отвечает за предоставление данных.

`PagerAdapter` – это базовый абстрактный класс, для которого разработчик дописывает реализацию так, как ему надо. Существует распространенная стандартная (частичная) реализация `PagerAdapter`, которая работает с фрагментами – это `FragmentPagerAdapter`. Разработчику остается только создать фрагмент и определить кол-во страниц.

Comment: @xTIGRx почитайте http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom.html с самого начала! Обо всем что вы спросили написано в более ранних уроках!

Comment: @xTIGRx, если я верно вас понял, то вам нужен метод `setOffscreenPageLimit()`.

Comment: Не знаю, я где то на форуме прочитал, что ViewPager так устроен, что создает объект слева и справа...тоесть в памяти 3 штуки создаются...так вот мне нужно их до 4 сделать. В андро прочитал, да видимо это. как раз с параметром int, завтра попробую, Спасибо :)

Comment: а какой метод отечает за то чтобы добавить фрагмент в ViewPager, просто я могу обратиться к фрагменту только после пролистывания право или влево до нужного фрагмента, а после уже обращяться к нему по индексу. так как он висит в памяти но видимо не добавился в ViewPager, что странно...просто мне нужно получается выполнить тот метод который выполняет проилстывание, чтобы добавить его в ViewPager для обращения к нему через index.

Answer (score 4):

[@xTIGRx](/users/22339/xtigrx), послушайте, зачем вы в это вообще полезли, если даже русскоязычную статью прочитать не в состоянии? А ведь ответы на все ваши вопросы содержатся в том же туториале по `ViewPager`'у, ссылку на который вам дал выше [[@katso](/users/6520/katso)](/users/6520/katso).

> тогда что делает это? PageFragment, pageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER); Что создает это и это onCreate и onCreateView.

Цитата из туториала: *"В onCreate читаем номер страницы из аргументов. Далее формируем цвет из рандомных компонентов. Он будет использоваться для фона страниц, чтобы визуально отличать одну страницу от другой.
В onCreateView создаем View, находим на нем TextView, пишем ему простой текст с номером страницы и ставим фоновый цвет.
Т.е. на вход у нас идет номер страницы, а на выходе получаем фрагмент, который отображает этот номер и имеет случайный фоновый цвет"*.

> что создает это new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

Цитата из туториала: *"В onCreate создаем адаптер и устанавливаем его для ViewPager. Также для ViewPager создаем обработчик событий. Он имеет три метода:
onPageSelected – дает номер текущей отображенной страницы
onPageScrollStateChanged – сообщает нам о состоянии, в котором находится скроллер (SCROLL_STATE_IDLE – ничего не скролится, SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING – пользователь «тащит» страницу, SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING – скроллер долистывает страницу до конца)"*.

И т.д.

---

В общем, могу дать вам несколько советов:

1. Не ждите, что вам всё разжуют и положат в рот готовое. Учитесь думать и искать решение самостоятельно.
2. Перечитайте уроки по ссылкам, что вам дал [[@katso](/users/6520/katso)](/users/6520/katso). Потом перечитайте ещё раз. И ещё. Закрепляйте каждый урок на практике.
3. Подучите английский. Знать английский на уровне, достаточном для чтения и понимания технической документации — это совсем не сложно, было бы желание.

Если после выполнения всех вышеперечисленных пунктов у вас всё ещё будут возникать подобные проблемы — бросайте это дело, не ваше это. Лучше выберите другое занятие по душе.